# To apply permission for by the name of Cloud9 environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

I have a Cloud9 environment named 'mydev'

and ARN is this below.

`arn:aws:cloud9:ap-northeast-1:678100228555:environment:6578dcc0f39e4d00a0089c225a5b6de8`

Now I want to restrict this by the name of environment.

Currently, my permission is like this below.

```
    {
        "Sid": "cloud9",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "cloud9:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:cloud9:*:*:environment:*"
    },
```

Is it possible to restrict such as (this code is wrong though)

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:cloud9:*:*:environment:*/mydev"
```

Comment: You can use tags to control access to your Cloud9 environment.